# Разный текст кнопки в зависимости от того авторизован пользователь или нет

Tags: php

Нужно, чтобы на кнопке отображался текст:

- "Вход", если пользователь не вошёл в свою учётную запись
- "Выход" если пользователь в учётную запись вошёл

Как это выполнить на PHP?

Comment: А как вы проверяете на сайте вошёл он или нет? Этим же флагом и текст выводите.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan, вот я и хочу узнать как это сделать с помощью PHP. Можете написать ответ, я проплюсую

Comment: как выполнить: найти учебную статью по авторизации пользователей, изучить и сделать. Если вы уж что-то пробовали, приведите код и что не получается. авторизация - сравнительно крупная часть проекта, содержащая много кода. Что вы хотите увидеть в ответе?

Answer (score 1):

```
         session_start();  
if($_SESSION['user']){
     $en= "вход";
    }else{
            $en= "Выход";
        }
          echo '<input type="button" value='.$en.' /><br />';
```

Comment: А как я узнаю, что полльзователь авторизован или нет?

Comment: @Kniga, поправил